# How to get sum of all row of the column from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an html table

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th style="width: 300px;">Activity</th>
            <th>QTY</th> 
            <th>RATE</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
                <tr>
                    <td>09/01/2020</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <strong>Test</strong><br />
                        Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br />
                        1TestBiraz
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">78</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">56</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">99</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>09/01/2020</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <strong>qwert</strong><br />
                        Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br />
                        asd
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">8</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">4</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">32</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>09/01/2020</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <strong> Leave</strong><br />
                        Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br />
                        asd
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">8</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">4</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">32</td>
                </tr>
  
    </tbody>


</table>

<div>
<a style="margin-left: 305px;">BALANCE DUE</a>
<strong>$800.00</strong>
</div>
```

The value of the amount is dynamic and there might be multiple row. Right Now I have done hard coded for $800.00. How can I sum the value of all Amount Column and display in Balance Due. I tried by couldn't get there.

https://jsfiddle.net/n6qo3u1b/

Comment: Are you looking for amount * rate or? where should we get the individual prices from

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Individual Prices can be get from quantity*rate

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried and it worked already took a idea from answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the prices from Quantity and Rate then you can do it like.

```
var price = 0;
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var rate = +$(this).find("td:nth-last-child(3)").text();
  var amount = +$(this).find("td:nth-last-child(2)").text();

  price = price + (rate * amount);
})

$('.price strong').text('$' + price)
```

Please note I've added the class `price` to the div that surrounds the "price/strong"

**Demo**

```js
var price = 0;
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var rate = +$(this).find("td:nth-last-child(3)").text();
  var amount = +$(this).find("td:nth-last-child(2)").text();

  price = price + (rate * amount);
})

$('.price strong').text('$' + price)
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

td,
th {
  /*border: 1px solid #dddddd;*/
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead {
  background: #DCE9F1
}

thead tr th {
  color: #4F90BB;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 50%;
}

hr {
  color: #5A97BF;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1px;
}

hr.new4 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-primary">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th style="width: 300px;">Activity</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>RATE</th>
      <th>AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


    <tr>
      <td>09/01/2020</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <strong>Test</strong><br /> Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br /> 1TestBiraz
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">78</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">56</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>09/01/2020</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <strong>qwert</strong><br /> Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br /> asd
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">8</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">4</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>09/01/2020</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <strong> Leave</strong><br /> Manish Rijal - JOB# 12345 <br /> asd
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">8</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">4</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">32</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>


</table>

<hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #5A97BF" />

<div class="price">
  <a style="margin-left: 305px;">BALANCE DUE</a>
  <strong>$800.00</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with vanilla javascript like so:

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child')
const arr = Array.from(nodes);

const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc += Number(curr.textContent)
}, 0)

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This does not multiple quantity and rate together to get the price.

Comment: the user asked how to get the sum of all the "amount" columns

Comment: Yes but I do believe that the op want the price updated, if you read the comment he wants the price to be a multiplication between rate and amount. I know the question is not clear regarding this.